# Liferay : ExceptionInInitializerError right after calling the FriendlyURL

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I am running Liferay 6.2 version with Tomcat 7.0.62.
I launch the server from IntelliJ IDE (version 2021.1.1) and everything goes well until the step where I see in logs FriendlyURL : /home
I have right after : Exception in thread "liferay/hot-deploy1" java.lang.Liferay.ExceptionInInitializerError
I don't know what this error means.

Here is my tomcat server launching log :

```
juin 10, 2021 8:52:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
juin 10, 2021 8:52:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
juin 10, 2021 8:52:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 370946 ms
Traitement de la friendlyURL : /home
Exception in thread "liferay/hot_deploy-1" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.liferay.ibm.icu.impl.ICUResourceBundle.<clinit>(ICUResourceBundle.java:464)
    at com.liferay.ibm.icu.util.UResourceBundle.getBundleInstance(UResourceBundle.java:104)
    at com.liferay.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator.<clinit>(Transliterator.java:1824)
    at com.liferay.util.Normalizer.<clinit>(Normalizer.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.FriendlyURLNormalizerImpl.normalize(FriendlyURLNormalizerImpl.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.FriendlyURLNormalizerImpl.normalize(FriendlyURLNormalizerImpl.java:39)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FriendlyURLNormalizerUtil.normalize(FriendlyURLNormalizerUtil.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceHelper.getFriendlyURL(LayoutLocalServiceHelper.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceHelper.getFriendlyURL(LayoutLocalServiceHelper.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceHelper.getFriendlyURLMap(LayoutLocalServiceHelper.java:127)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.addLayout(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceVirtualLayoutsAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceVirtualLayoutsAdvice.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.cache.ThreadLocalCacheAdvice.invoke(ThreadLocalCacheAdvice.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.addLayout(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(LayoutLocalServiceUtil.java:476)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.util.FileSystemImporter.addLayout(FileSystemImporter.java:736)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.util.FileSystemImporter.addLayouts(FileSystemImporter.java:890)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.util.FileSystemImporter.setupSitemap(FileSystemImporter.java:1313)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.util.FileSystemImporter.doImportResources(FileSystemImporter.java:904)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.util.ResourceImporter.importResources(ResourceImporter.java:38)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.messaging.ResourcesImporterHotDeployMessageListener.initialize(ResourcesImporterHotDeployMessageListener.java:226)
    at com.liferay.resourcesimporter.messaging.ResourcesImporterHotDeployMessageListener.onDeploy(ResourcesImporterHotDeployMessageListener.java:278)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.HotDeployMessageListener.doReceive(HotDeployMessageListener.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SerialDestination$1.run(SerialDestination.java:67)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
    at com.liferay.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:191)
    at com.liferay.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
    at com.liferay.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
    ... 58 more
```

Can you help please?

Comment: I can't find the reference, but there was something in the past about a JRE release with a version number higher than 255, creating a problem. To see if this is what you suffer from, downgrade to a lower number and try again. You're on a long outdated version of Liferay and might want to consider upgrading

Comment: I tried downgrading, but it didn't solve the problem.